# How to take screenshot in cucumber using tag name

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, screenshot

I have the following code written in `Selenium/Java` but I want to parameterize this code and add the tag name for which the screenshot is taken:

```
@Then("^Take Screenshot$")
public void tearDown() {
    // take the screenshot at the end of every test
    String location = "D:/ubdd/screenshots/";
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy h-m-s");
    Date date = new Date();
    File scrFile = 
    ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    // now save the screenshto to a file some place
    try {
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File(location + 
    dateFormat.format(date)+".png"));
    System.out.println("Screenshot saved");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the [guides for asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), specifically [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Before hook and add the Scenario object` as argument. Cucumber will inject this with the currently executing scenario.

```
private Scenario sce;

    @Before
    public void beforeHook(Scenario scenario) {
         this.sce = scenario


        List<String> tags = sce.getSourceTagNames();
    }
```

You can access the stored scenario object in your step definitions to call the getSourceTagNames() to get tags

Answer (score 0):

If your tests are single-threaded you can use the Before Hook to get the scenario being executed as @Grasshoper mentioned and store it in a global variable and then access scenario from the step being executed to retrieve the tag names:

```
private Scenario scenario;

@Before
public void setUp(Scenario scenario) {
  this.scenario = scenario;
}

@Then("^Take Screenshot$")
public void tearDown() {
  this.scenario.getSourceTagNames();
  ...
}
```

For multi-threaded executions I would use use a `ConcurrentHashMap` to maintain a link between the Thread ID and the Scenario being executed. You can then retrieve the Scenario being executed from the Step using the Thread ID.